# Message Class in Akka: Sending an array/buffer as a message

Tags: scala, akka

I've recently started learning the Akka framework using Scala. I know that we can use message class as shown below if we want to send variables as part of the message:

```
case class Work(start: Int, nrOfElements: Int) extends PiMessage
```

How can I send arrays as part of such messages? For eg. the line below doesn't work.

```
case class WorkSend(buff: Array[Int],Dim : Int)
```

**EDIT:**

I'm getting an out of bound exception for the following code:

```
case class WorkSend(buff: Array[Int], Dim : Int)
```

At Master:

```
val buff = Array[Int](10)
     for (i <- 0 to Dim - 1) //Dim is 10
        buff(i) = matrixA(0)(i)
     worker ! WorkSend(buff)
```

At Worker:

```
def receive = {
      case WorkSend(buff) =>

        for (i <- 0 to 9)
        println("Item received: " + buff(i))
        println("Work Done")
        sender ! WorkDone

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not?

```
import akka.actor._


case class Start(buf: Array[String]) {
  override def toString = buf.mkString("->")
}

object Local extends App {

  implicit val system = ActorSystem("LocalSystem")
  val localActor = system.actorOf(Props[LocalActor], name = "LocalActor")  
  localActor ! Start(Array("A", "B", "C"))                                                          
}

class LocalActor extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case s: Start =>
      println("LocalActor got: " + s)
  }
}
```

> LocalActor got: A->B->C

--

The problem is a little different.
How to copy from matrix (Array of Arrays to Array)
Answer: you do not need to create any intermediate buffers. Just use matrix as a vector and pass it to the actor.

```
scala> val m = Array(Array(1,2), Array(3,4))
m: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(1, 2), Array(3, 4))

scala> m(1)
res38: Array[Int] = Array(3, 4)

WorkSend(m(1))
```

Comment: At what line do you see exception ?  `buff(i) = matrixA(0)(i)`  ? check the dimensions of this data structures.

Comment: `val buff = Array[Int](10)` - this line creates Array with one element only. Not array of ten!